# Android Auto prevent dimming

Tags: google-maps, android-auto

When using Android Auto Google maps on new Toyota Corolla the car screen dims as soon as the phone screen timeouts.
If I unlock the phone car screen goes bright again.

How to prevent car screen from dimming?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue. Also, please review the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I used was to put the screen time to 30 minutes.
Later Goolge update Android auto and it doesn't dim anymore.